# ActiveX DLL Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, activex

OK while I never thought in 2012 I would be writing my first ActiveX control (and yes there is a good reason for it) I am struggling with getting it running under Windows 7 (x64).

**The Solution Short Story:**  I was missing /codebase from some of my regasm calls and also mixing up 32 and 64 bit processes, but that wasn't being helped by the standard VS2010 command prompt mixing up 32 and 64 bit paths for regasm and cscript.

**The long story follows:**

I have been bouncing between

<strike>[Creating an ActiveX control in .Net using C#](http://haseebakhtar.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/)</strike>

(**Oops**  I had the wrong link .. although it looks like the link I initially supplied was someone copying the original blog page)

[Creating an ActiveX control in .Net using C#](http://www.olavaukan.com/2010/08/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/)

and

[C# ActiveX control (CSActiveX)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSActiveX-c3f43e7d)

And I appear to be building the projects successfully (for the latter one I had to change the resource compiler location to the correct location).

For the first project I am using the suggested installer, for the second project I am trying to use regasm directly.

But after this it all goes down hill.  I try and register the all's but either:

1. I have no idea how I should be registering them, or:
2. I have no idea how I should be registering them.

My test case has been a simple JScript file containing

```
var x = new ActiveXObject( "name of object" );
```

Which fails with the error:

> test.js(1,1) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Automation Server can't create object

I am not sure if this is a permissions issue, or a 32 vs 64 bit issue or a combination.

A lot of sites offering help on ActiveX are assuming you will be accessing it via a web page , so I have tried looking at IE permissions (even though I want to load the control into a 3rd part program).

I know if I use either the 'framework' or 'framework64' versions of regasm I can control where in the registry entries get put - and I have seen some references to running cscript as either 32 or 64 bit (which possible affects what part of the registry is searched) depending on the cmd shell invoked (and I have tried both ways, as well as trying an "administrator" shell).

So basically at this point I have no idea what I am doing or what I should be doing.

My goal is to register an ActiveX control on Windows 7 x64 and have it be able to be loaded by:

1. A test .js script running from the default Windows command prompt
2. Load the same control into something like Excel 2007 VBA (for testing only)
3. Load the control into a 3rd part application (RSView Studio from Rockwell) and have it hosted within a VBA application (and I need to check if this isa 32 or 64bit program .. I suspect the former)

**Notes**

For the project that users the installer (Creating an ActiveX control in .Net using C#), it installs the code into "c:\program Files (x86)\" and looking with regedit I find entries under "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\"  which I believe is telling me that the DLL was installed as a 32 bit process.  I have tried running my cscript test from both a 32 and 64 bit cmd and they both fail.  NOTE that the installer was creating the equivalent of "regasm /codebase" when it ran.

For the project where I tried using regasm to register it (C# ActiveX control (CSActiveX)), it has some additional code for registering an ActiveX COM control.  This code mentions registering 32 bit in-process servers (see ActiveXCtrlHelpers.cs)

(BTW I'm also cursing auto correct in Safari/Lion at the moment, keeps changing lower case "DLL" into "all")

---

**Edit 2012-08-07**

Prompted by Art's answer I discovered:

**From standard VS2010 command prompt**

When running 'regasm /codebase' through the standard VS2010 command prompt (and as administrator to allow regasm to perform changes), the entries got dumped into the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID  and the test scripts failed from the same prompt.

However I can see the ActiveX control in Excel 2007 (32 bit)

**From x64 Win64 VS2010 command prompt**

When running under the VS2010 x64 Win64 command prompt (again as admin) the registry entries appeared under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID but this time the test scripts worked from the same prompt and also from a standard Windows cmd prompt (however they fail from a 32 bit prompt)

But!! I can't see the active X control from Excel 2007 (32 bit)

<strike>Now I just need to figure out what the windows equivalent of the *nix 'which' command to ensure which regasm I am using)</strike> the 'where' command

Looking at the VS2010 and Windows 7 command prompts:

```
    VS2010 (standard prompt): cscript => c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe
                              regasm  => c:\windows\Microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe

    VS2010 (x64 Win 64):      cscript => c:\windows\system32\cscript
                              regasm  => c:\windows\Microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe

    Windows 7  std. prompt:   cscript => c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe

    Windows 7 32 bit prompt:  cscript => c:\windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe
```

This is all starting to make some of my confusion understandable.  I have been unknowingly mixing and matching 32 and 64 bit systems, but the VS2010 standard prompt didn't help either!

(and my latest peeve - VS2010 saving files as UTF-8 with BOM)

Comment: You need to use `regsvr32` (in your Windows System folder) to register the COM DLL; it's not enough to just use `regasm`, which registers it with .NET. `regsvr Drive:\Full\PathTo\Your\ActiveXLib.DLL` from a command-prompt. (Same command with a `-u` parameter before the path will unregister it as well.)

Comment: @KenWhite I assume c:\windows\system32 and not c:\windowsSysWOW64 ?

Comment: Depends on whether you're registering a 32 or 64 bit control. For 32-bit, use the one in SysWOW64; for 64-bit, use the one in System32 (yeah, seems wrong, but it's not).

Comment: @KenWhite if the control is built as AnyCPU then would the method of registering it depend on whether the final host program was 32 or 64?

Comment: Peter, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that. :-( I'd suspect you'd want to use the one appropriate for the app the control was going to be used in, though. I'll see if I can dig up any info.

Comment: @KenWhite It's kinda moot at the moment.  Either use of regsvr32 gives  me an error "The module <name> was loaded but the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found.", and I got that on both of my projects.  FWIW Regasm wasn't giving me any errors at all

Comment: Did you to change the IE Option Security Settings for Local Intranet Zone, the option "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" to Enabled or Prompt?

Comment: Ah. That one I can help with <g>. [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/17/10237911.aspx) answers that better than I can.

Comment: @KenWhite I go with that, but neither of the original projects implemented that entry point, yet they profess to work.

Comment: Is your ActiveX control assembly strongly named and installed to the GAC? If you are not installing it to the GAC, then use regasm /codebase [assemblyname].  If you do not use the codebase option, then the machine will not be able to locate your ActiveX COM assembly unless it is in the same folder as the calling process. Also, you mentioned that your are executing this on a 64bit box -- how are you compiling the ActiveX Assembly? If the calling (hosting) process is x64 then you must make sure that you are compiling the ActiveX assembly as either Any CPU or x64.

Comment: @Art Both projects are built as AnyCPU.  Neither are strongly named (can you suggest names for me?  I'm zonked right now :-) ) Also see my notes about where code keeps ending up.

Comment: @PeterM Do the regasm /codebase on the assembly.  You need to do this in order for the new ActiveXObject( "name of object" ); call to work since it is not strongly named and installed in the GAC.  You do NOT need to strongly name it in order for it to work, but you DO need to do a regasm /codebase on the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work both via IE and vbscript by doing the following:

1. Create .NET class library named 'ActiveXTest'
2. Add a class named MyObject which is defined as follows:

   ```
   namespace ActiveXTest
   {
       [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
       [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("ActiveXTest.MyObject")]
       [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("df2dac4d-ba8a-4ecc-b76e-958c1bc32f1f")]
       public class MyObject
       {
           public string HelloWorld()
           {
               return "This is Hello World from the COM component!";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Compile the class.  Go to the folder where you compiled the class and do the following from a Visual Studio command prompt: regasm /codebase ActiveXTest.dll
4. To test from a .vbs script, create a file in notepad call test.vbs.  type the following into the file:

   ```
   Dim myObject
   set myObject = CreateObject("ActiveXTest.MyObject")
   MsgBox(myObject.HelloWorld)
   ```

Open a command prompt and navigate to where where you created the Test.vbs and type: wscript test.vbs.  A dialog should be displayed stating "This is Hellow World from the COM component"

1. To test this from IE, I created a TEST.HTML file with the following contents:

   ```
   <HTML>
       <HEAD>
           <script language="JScript" language="JavaScript">
             var obj = new ActiveXObject("ActiveXTest.MyObject");
             alert(obj.HelloWorld());          
           </script>
       </HEAD>

      <body>
          <span>nothing to see here!</span>
      <body>
   </HTML>
   ```

Open the TEST.HTML file in IE.  You will get a warning about the ActiveX control; just say Yes to allow the interaction.  You will get an alert dialog stating "This is Hello World from the COM Component".

Similar steps can be used to make it work from a .js file or from Excel VBA.  Note that if you change the COM method signature of the ActiveX assembly I believe you will need to re-register it.

Comment: I followed your solution (with 1 exception) and had good and bad results.  The exception was having to get admin privileges on the VS2010 command prompt to run regasm.  Bad results - this process failed when using the standard VS2010 command prompt (and running the script file from with in the same prompt).  Good results - it worked when using the VS2010 x64 Win64 command prompt.  In the registry, regasm from the standard prompt puts the entries in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID while the x64 regasm puts them in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID

Comment: see my latest update for why things seems to be failing for me .. it looks like the cscript path in a standard VS2010 prompt isn't matching the regasm it is using!

Comment: You need to have elevated priviledges to run regasm. The two keys you are describing are the x86 and the x64 registration entries for the assembly.  When it comes to COM, a 64bit process can only talk to a 64bit COM component and a 32 bit process can only talk to a 32bit COM component.  Do a regasm.exe /codebase using both the regasm found in the Framework64 and Framework folders found in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\ folder for the appropriate .NET framework that you are using.  This will assure that you have the correct entry in both the 64bit register and 32bit registry.

Comment: Also, make sure that your .NET assembly is compiled as AnyCPU (which I believe you have already said it is).  This will assure that it can be addressible by by 32bit and 64bit COM host processes.

Comment: It all makes senses now.  But that VS2010 mix'n'match was killing me.  I project I was testing with the installer was generating the codebase registry entry in the 32 bit section, but I obviously missed testing that one with the correct 32bit cscript.