# How to identify a specific ActiveX Interface based on limited information

Tags: vba, interface, activex

I am in the process of developing an ActiveX control for embedding in Rockwell Automation's Factory Talk View.  (See [ActiveX DLL Error: Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834832/activex-dll-error-solved) to see how great a start I got off to!)

At the moment I have an ActiveX control that seems to embed into the host system OK, but is not fully integrated into the VBA process.  I believe that this is because I have not implemented some specific COM interface that is required, but I have no documentation as to what that is.  I do know that standard MS controls like the Microsoft Forms 2.0 controls **do** implement the required interface and fully integrate.

The key functionality I am missing relates to a property that I need to set in order for my VBA code to actually see the ActiveX object.  This property can be seen when opening the property panel for **any** activeX control placed on a Factory Talk screen, but NOT when looking at the properties of ActiveX controls embedded in (for example) Excel.  Thus I am probably trying to chase down some custom Rockwell implementation.  I am hoping that SO might be able to give me some aid into how to track down what I want based on recognizing the functionality it implements.

Now to the actual property.  In Factory Talk the property is called "ExposeToVBA", and has a type "long".  You have a choice of 3 values selected from a drop down list:

```
    Not Exposed         - When set to this, the controls name is not even visible to VBA code
    Type Info Extension - Not sure what this does
    VBA Control         - VBA code can see and interact with the control.
```

When I select anything other than "Not Exposed" for my control, I get a warning dialog box with no text on it.   For other controls I need to set it to "VBA Control" in order to interact with it in the VBA code (d'oh)

I suspect that the value of this property is translated into some calls to an ActiveX interface on the target control.

**The Question**

What I want to do is identify what interfaces something like a "Forms 2.0 Label" implements that would match the above functionality.  And also perhaps how I could translate this into my C# based control (based on [C# ActiveX control (CSActiveX)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSActiveX-c3f43e7d))

I know its a long shot, but I'd appreciate any and all suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became moot when I found a canned Active-x control that had the functionality that I needed.

FWIW This is what I believe that I used: [DMGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310494/2D-Graph-ActiveX-control-in-Cplusplus-with-ATL-no)

Comment: What was the canned Activex you used? I am trying to program accessibility to the same type except mine in a CSV file housed locally.

Comment: @Bruce See the edit to my answer for the active X control I used